# dplyr::mutate_at() with external variables and conditional on their values

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataset in long-format (i.e. multiple observations per `ID`). Each `ID` contains multiple visits at which the individual was diagnosed for disease (in the toy example, I show 3 but in my real data I have as many as 30), which are coded in consecutive columns (`disease1-disease3`). A value of 1 means they were diagnosed with the disease at the time of `diagnosis_dt`, and 0 means the did not have it. For each `ID`, I'm interested in summarizing whether or not they had any disease across all visits where `diagnosis_dt` falls **between** `start_dt` and `end_dt`. Some `ID`s don't have diagnosis information, and consequently are coded as `NA`s in the respective columns. I'd still like to keep this information.

A toy example of my dataset is below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

ex_dat <- data.frame(ID = c(rep("a",3),
                  rep("b",4),
                  rep("c",5)),
                  start_dt = as.Date(c(rep("2009-01-01",3),
                                       rep("2009-04-01",4),
                                       rep("2009-02-01",5))),
                  end_dt = as.Date(c(rep("2010-12-31",3),
                                rep("2011-03-31",4),
                                rep("2011-01-31",5))),
           diagnosis_dt = c(as.Date(c("2011-01-03","2010-11-01","2009-12-01")),
                            as.Date(c("2011-04-03","2010-11-01","2009-12-01","2011-12-01")),
                            rep(NA,5)),
           disease1 = c(c(1,0,0),
                        c(1,1,0,1),
                        rep(NA,5)),
           disease2 = c(c(1,1,0),
                        c(0,0,0,1),
                        rep(NA,5)),
           disease3 = c(c(0,0,0),
                        c(0,0,1,0),
                        rep(NA,5))
           )
```

The desired output is:

```
  ID disease1 disease2 disease3
1  a        0        1        0
2  b        1        0        1
3  c       NA       NA       NA
```

I've been trying this for hours now and my latest attempt is:

```
out <- ex_dat %>% group_by(ID) %>%
           mutate_at(vars(disease1:disease3),
                     function(x) ifelse(!is.na(.$diagnosis_dt) & 
                                          between(.$diagnosis_dt,.$start_dt,.$end_dt) & 
                                          sum(x)>0,
                                        1,0)) %>%
           slice(1) %>%
           select(ID,disease1:disease3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach with the `dplyr` `across` functionality (version >= 1.0.0):

```
library(dplyr)
ex_dat %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(across(-one_of(c("start_dt","end_dt","diagnosis_dt")),
                   ~ if_else(any(diagnosis_dt > start_dt & diagnosis_dt < end_dt & .),
                             1, 0)))
## A tibble: 3 x 4
#  ID    disease1 disease2 disease3
#  <fct>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 a            0        1        0
#2 b            1        0        1
#3 c           NA       NA       NA
```

Note that using the `&` operator on the integer column `.` converts to logical. I'm using the `-one_of` tidyselect verb because then we don't even need to know how many diseases there are. The columns that are actively being `group_by`-ed are automatically excluded.

Your version isn't working because 1) you need to summarize, not mutate, and 2) inside the function call `.` refers to the column that is being worked on, not the data from piping. Instead, you need to access those columns without `$` from the calling environment.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution using `filter` to eliminate the rows that do not meet the desired condition and then use `complete` to complete the missing groups with NA.

```
library(tidyverse)

ex_dat %>%
  #Group by ID 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  # Stay with the rows for which diagnosis_dt is between start_dt and end_dt
  filter(diagnosis_dt >= start_dt & diagnosis_dt <= end_dt ) %>%
  # summarize all variables that start with disease by taking its max value
  summarize_at(vars(starts_with("disease")), max) %>%
  # Complete the missing IDs, those that only had NA or did not meet the criteria in  
  # the filter
  complete(ID)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  ID    disease1 disease2 disease3
# <fct>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1 a            0        1        0
# 2 b            1        0        1
# 3 c           NA       NA       NA
```